# PHP Page Not Showing Up On Browser And Can't See Source Code

Tags: php, html

I was running this php file correctly and it showed up on the browser yesterday, but today, all of a sudden, I wasn't able to see the file correctly and also couldn't find the code in the source code via browser.

Also, this is the tutorial I was following: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAkKC8DKN9A

Here is the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Member System - Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    $form = "<form action='./login.php' method='post'>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='user' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='loginbtn' value='Login' /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>";

    if ($_POST['loginbtn']) {
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if ($user) {
            if ($password) {

                require("connect.php");

                password = md5 (md5("kjfiufj".$password."Fjf56fj"));

                echo "$password";

                $query = mysql_query("");

                mysql_close();
            }
            else 
                echo "You must enter your password. $form";
        }
        else
            echo "You must enter your username. $form";
    }
    else 
        echo $form;

    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this code is totally unsafe to be used as a live site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' on line 41. Replace

`password = md5 (md5("kjfiufj".$password."Fjf56fj"));` to

`$password = md5 (md5("kjfiufj".$password."Fjf56fj"));`

Comment: Thank You! This solution worked! I can't make it the answer right now though :/

Comment: :) no problem... Keep coding.

Comment: @StephenKim having used error reporting, would have signaled an undefined constant password notice. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php